# coupon code should apply once we cancel the order

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, coupon

If we applied coupon code and completed order.

Once we cancel the order, then coupon code should become applicable again, but it can't be used anymore. Please help me, it's strange default Magento behavior.

Please help me soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is default Magento behaviour - if the payment fails / the order is canceled before it, then the coupon code will not be free to be reused.

There're few modules that change this behaviour.
Quick googling gave me f/e:

http://magetechno.com/cancel-order-coupon-code-reuse.html

Here's description for the situation:
http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/quick-fix-coupon-codes-used-up-on-incomplete-transactions/

To avoid link being removed and for future reference I'm copy-pastying the contents of that post: *(all credits go to **MageBase.com** for this solution, it's untested but from the looks of it - should do it's job):*

**app/code/local/Orchid/CouponFix/Model/Observer.php**

```
<?php
class Orchid_CouponFix_Model_Observer
{
    public function cancel($observer)
    {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $order = $event->getPayment()->getOrder();
        if ($order->canCancel()) {
        if ($code = $order->getCouponCode()) {
            $coupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($code, 'coupon_code');
            $coupon->setTimesUsed($coupon->getTimesUsed()-1);
            $coupon->save();
            if($customerId = $order->getCustomerId()) {
                if ($customerCoupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule_customer')->loadByCustomerRule($customerId, $coupon->getId())) {
                    $customerCoupon->setTimesUsed($customerCoupon->getTimesUsed()-1);
                    $customerCoupon->save();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/Orchid/CouponFix/etc/config.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
            <Orchid_CouponFix>
                    <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Orchid_CouponFix>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <couponfix>
                <class>Orchid_CouponFix_Model</class>
            </couponfix>
    </models>
    <events>
        <sales_order_payment_cancel>
        <observers>
          <orchid_couponfix_observer>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Orchid_CouponFix_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>cancel</method>
          </orchid_couponfix_observer>
        </observers>
        </sales_order_payment_cancel>     
    </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

**app/etc/modules/Orchid_CouponFix.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Orchid_CouponFix>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Orchid_CouponFix>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: thanks , i used `Orchid` module, when i try to cance lthe order i got theis error : `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'salesrule.coupon_code' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT `salesrule`.* FROM `salesrule` WHERE (`salesrule`.`coupon_code`='123456')` please help me

Comment: also i downloaded this extension : http://magetechno.com/cancel-order-coupon-code-reuse.html but there is app/etc/module.xml file is not there, please help me

Comment: I hope it Magento 2.2.6 cancel functionality works as expected with coupon code reuse.  How to develop it programatically

Comment: Could you let me know the actual path and function of this code which reverts coupon code so that it could be reuse tried to debug in magento/module-sales/controller/Adminhtml/order/cancel.php but was unable to get actual functionality which could be used in my customize cancel functionality

Answer (score 3):

You could create an event observer for `order_cancel_after`. Then if the order was placed by a customer (`$order->getCustomerId() > 0`), you can update the `salesrule_coupon_usage` table and lower the value of `times_used` for this coupon.

- Get the applied coupon codes for an order by checking the `coupon_code` attribute of an order and keep in mind that some extensions may accept more than one code and separate them by commas: `$couponCodes = explode(',', $order->getCouponCode());`
- For finding the correct `coupon_id`, see `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Coupon::loadByCode()`
- For decreasing `times_used`, you could check `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Resource_Coupon_Usage::updateCustomerCouponTimesUsed()`, which increases `times_used`

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer doesn't work for me in Magento 1.9.3+ So i modified and added some code to the observer cancel function. This should do the trick:

```
public function cancel($observer)
{
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $order = $event->getPayment()->getOrder();

    if ($order->canCancel()) {
        $customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
        $code = $order->getCouponCode();

        if ($code) {
            $rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load($code, 'name');
            $rule->setTimesUsed($rule->getTimesUsed() - 1);
            $rule->save();

            $coupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon')->loadByCode($code);
            $coupon->setTimesUsed($coupon->getTimesUsed() - 1);
            $coupon->save();

            if ($customerId) {
                /* @var Mage_SalesRule_Model_Resource_Coupon_Usage $couponUsage */
                $couponUsage = Mage::getResourceModel('salesrule/coupon_usage');
                $couponUsage->getReadConnection()->delete($couponUsage->getMainTable(), [
                    'coupon_id = ?' => $coupon->getId(),
                    'customer_id = ?' => $customerId
                ]);

                $customerCoupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule_customer')->loadByCustomerRule($customerId, $rule->getId());

                if ($customerCoupon) {
                    $customerCoupon->setTimesUsed($customerCoupon->getTimesUsed() - 1);
                    $customerCoupon->save();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I confirm that the solution works on 1.9+ and take care of every tables that need to be edited. Great work

Comment: @Jesse Visser if guest is going to apply coupon means ? where to do the changes

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above answer by @Jesse Visser in my Magento 1.9.0.1 but when I try to place an order it gives an error to try again later so I have updated the above code, any improvement on my below code would be great.

```
<?php
class Orchid_CouponFix_Model_Observer
{
    public function cancel($observer)
    {
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $order = $event->getPayment()->getOrder();
        if ($order->canCancel()) {
            if ($code = $order->getCouponCode()) {
                $coupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon')->load($code, 'code');
                $coupon_id = $coupon->getCouponId();
                $rule_id = $coupon->getRuleId();
                if($customerId = $order->getCustomerId()){
                    // Update or Delete record in salesrule_coupon_usage Table
                    $tableName = $resource->getTableName('salesrule_coupon_usage');
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM {$tableName} WHERE coupon_id={$coupon_id} AND customer_id={$customerId}";
                    $coupon_usage = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
                    $coupon_usage = $coupon_usage[0]['times_used'];
                    if($coupon_usage==1){
                        $query = "DELETE FROM {$tableName} WHERE coupon_id={$coupon_id} AND customer_id={$customerId}";
                    }else{
                        $coupon_usage = $coupon_usage-1;
                        $query = "UPDATE {$tableName} SET times_used={$coupon_usage} WHERE coupon_id={$coupon_id} AND customer_id={$customerId}";
                    }
                    $writeConnection->query($query);

                    // Update or Delete record in salesrule_customer Table
                    $tableName = $resource->getTableName('salesrule_customer');
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM {$tableName} WHERE rule_id={$rule_id} AND customer_id={$customerId}";
                    $coupon_usage = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
                    $coupon_usage = $coupon_usage[0]['times_used'];
                    if($coupon_usage==1){
                        $query = "DELETE FROM {$tableName} WHERE rule_id={$rule_id} AND customer_id={$customerId}";
                    }else{
                        $coupon_usage = $coupon_usage-1;
                        $query = "UPDATE {$tableName} SET times_used={$coupon_usage} WHERE rule_id={$rule_id} AND customer_id={$customerId}";
                    }
                    $writeConnection->query($query);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

For CE 1.7.0.2 installations with all security patches installed (up to SUPEE10975), the salesrule_coupon table must also be updated, Obeserver.php updated:

```
<?php
class Orchid_CouponFix_Model_Observer
{
    public function cancel($observer)
    {
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $order = $event->getPayment()->getOrder();
        if ($order->canCancel()) {
            if ($code = $order->getCouponCode()) {
                $coupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon')->load($code, 'code');
                $coupon_id = $coupon->getCouponId();
                $rule_id = $coupon->getRuleId();
                if($customerId = $order->getCustomerId()){
                    // Update or Delete record in salesrule_coupon_usage Table
                    $tableName = $resource->getTableName('salesrule_coupon_usage');
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM {$tableName} WHERE coupon_id={$coupon_id} AND customer_id={$customerId}";
                    $coupon_usage = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
                    $coupon_usage = $coupon_usage[0]['times_used'];
                    if($coupon_usage==1){
                        $query = "DELETE FROM {$tableName} WHERE coupon_id={$coupon_id} AND customer_id={$customerId}";
                    }else{
                        $coupon_usage = $coupon_usage-1;
                        $query = "UPDATE {$tableName} SET times_used={$coupon_usage} WHERE coupon_id={$coupon_id} AND customer_id={$customerId}";
                    }
                    $writeConnection->query($query);

                    // Update record in salesrule_coupon Table
                    $tableName = $resource->getTableName('salesrule_coupon');
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM {$tableName} WHERE coupon_id={$coupon_id}";
                    $coupon_usage = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
                    $coupon_usage = $coupon_usage[0]['times_used'];
                    if($coupon_usage==1){
                        $coupon_usage = 0;
                        $query = "UPDATE {$tableName} SET times_used={$coupon_usage} WHERE coupon_id={$coupon_id}";
                    }else{
                        $coupon_usage = $coupon_usage-1;
                        $query = "UPDATE {$tableName} SET times_used={$coupon_usage} WHERE coupon_id={$coupon_id}";
                    }
                    $writeConnection->query($query);                    

                    // Update or Delete record in salesrule_customer Table
                    $tableName = $resource->getTableName('salesrule_customer');
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM {$tableName} WHERE rule_id={$rule_id} AND customer_id={$customerId}";
                    $coupon_usage = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
                    $coupon_usage = $coupon_usage[0]['times_used'];
                    if($coupon_usage==1){
                        $query = "DELETE FROM {$tableName} WHERE rule_id={$rule_id} AND customer_id={$customerId}";
                    }else{
                        $coupon_usage = $coupon_usage-1;
                        $query = "UPDATE {$tableName} SET times_used={$coupon_usage} WHERE rule_id={$rule_id} AND customer_id={$customerId}";
                    }
                    $writeConnection->query($query);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.9

```
if ($code = $order->getCouponCode()) {
                    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
                    $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
                    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

                    $coupon = Mage::getModel('salesrule/coupon')->load($code, 'code');
                    $coupon_id = $coupon->getCouponId();
                    $rule_id = $coupon->getRuleId();

                    // Update record in salesrule_coupon Table
                    $tableName = 'salesrule_coupon';
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM {$tableName} WHERE coupon_id={$coupon_id}";
                    $coupon_usage = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
                    $coupon_usage = $coupon_usage[0]['times_used'];
                    if($coupon_usage > 0){
                        $coupon_usage = $coupon_usage-1;
                        $query = "UPDATE {$tableName} SET times_used={$coupon_usage} WHERE coupon_id={$coupon_id}";
                    }
                    $writeConnection->query($query);

                    if($customerId = $order->getCustomerId()){
                        // Update or Delete record in salesrule_coupon_usage Table
                        $tableName = 'salesrule_coupon_usage';
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM {$tableName} WHERE coupon_id={$coupon_id} AND customer_id={$customerId}";
                        $coupon_usage = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
                        $coupon_usage = $coupon_usage[0]['times_used'];
                        if($coupon_usage==1){
                            $query = "DELETE FROM {$tableName} WHERE coupon_id={$coupon_id} AND customer_id={$customerId}";
                        }else{
                            $coupon_usage = $coupon_usage-1;
                            $query = "UPDATE {$tableName} SET times_used={$coupon_usage} WHERE coupon_id={$coupon_id} AND customer_id={$customerId}";
                        }
                        $writeConnection->query($query);

                        // Update or Delete record in salesrule_customer Table
                        $tableName = 'salesrule_customer';
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM {$tableName} WHERE rule_id={$rule_id} AND customer_id={$customerId}";
                        $coupon_usage = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
                        $coupon_usage = $coupon_usage[0]['times_used'];
                        if($coupon_usage==1){
                            $query = "DELETE FROM {$tableName} WHERE rule_id={$rule_id} AND customer_id={$customerId}";
                        }else{
                            $coupon_usage = $coupon_usage-1;
                            $query = "UPDATE {$tableName} SET times_used={$coupon_usage} WHERE rule_id={$rule_id} AND customer_id={$customerId}";
                        }
                        $writeConnection->query($query);
                    }
                }
```